# Form has the wrong address in the URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have a confusion of addresses: Instead of going to page `127.0.0.1:8000/page1` when I insert `127.0.0.1:8000/begin` the view that should appear on `page1` it has the address `127.0.0.1:8000/begin` in the URL, and when accessing the second page that should have the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/page2` it shows me the view with the address `127.0.0.1:8000/page1` and this happens with the third and last page of the form returning the address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/page2` in the URL instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/page3`. Can anyone help me with this?

- `web.php`

```
Route::get('/begin', [HunterController::class, 'begin'])->name('begin');
Route::post('/page1', [HunterController::class, 'pageForm1'])->name('pageForm1');
Route::post('/page2', [HunterController::class, 'pageForm2'])->name('pageForm2');
Route::post('/page3', [HunterController::class, 'pageForm3'])->name('pageForm3');
Route::post('/submit', [HunterController::class, 'submitForm'])->name('submitForm');
```

- `HunterController.php`

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Models\HunterModel;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
    
    class HunterController extends Controller
    {
    
        public function begin()
        {
            return view('page1');
        }
    
        public function pageForm1(Request $request)
        {
            $validations = $request->validate([
                'name_hunter' => 'required|max:50',
                'email_hunter' => ['required','max:50','email', Rule::unique('hunters', 'email_hunter')],
                'age_hunter' => 'required|integer|min:13',
            ]);
    
            session()->put('page1', $validations);
    
            return view('page2');
        }
    
        public function pageForm2(Request $request)
        {
            $validations = $request->validate([
                'height_hunter' => 'required|numeric|min:1.50|max:2.50',
                'weight_hunter' => 'required|numeric|min:50.00|max:150.00',
                'type_hunter' => 'required','max:50','exists:type_hunters,description',
            ]);
    
            session()->put('page2', $validations);
    
            return view('page3');
        }
    
        public function pageForm3(Request $request)
        {
            $validations = $request->validate([
                'type_nen' => ['required','max:30','exists:type_nens,description',
                'type_blood' => ['required','exists:type_bloods,description',
            ]);
    
            session()->put('page3', $validations);
    
            return redirect()->route('submitForm');
        }
    
        public function submitForm()
        {
            $page1 = session()->get('page1');
            $page2 = session()->get('page2');
            $page3 = session()->get('page3');
    
            HunterModel::create([
                'name_hunter' => $page1['name_hunter'],
                'email_hunter' => $page1['email_hunter'],
                'age_hunter' => $page1['age_hunter'],
                'height_hunter' => $page2['height_hunter'],
                'weight_hunter' => $page2['weight_hunter'],
                'type_hunter' => $page2['type_hunter'],
                'type_nen' => $page3['type_nen'],
                'type_blood' => $page3['type_blood'],
            ]);
    
            session()->forget('page1');
            session()->forget('page2');
            session()->forget('page3');
    
            return redirect()->route('inicio');
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: in your begin method you are returning ```public function begin() {return view('page1'); }```  ... where as i believe it should return ```return view('begin'); ``` or something .... and even in the rest of the code your method is not returning you intended page/view/template

Comment: You want to access 127.0.0.1:8000/begin page but in your begin method you return you return page1 view, 127.0.0.1:8000/page1 page inside pageForm1 method you return page2 view, 127.0.0.1:8000/page2 page inside pageForm2 method you return page3 view. Verify which view you want to in invoking which method.